# Is there any way I can extract a table the isn't in a table/list in html

Tags: google-sheets

https://icodrops.com/ico-stats/

I'm trying to pull the table on this site into a google sheet.  Is this at all possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Simple? No. It's also not particularly efficient to do it within Google Sheets. You will need to use Apps Script for sure. And the only reason you would do this within the Google Sheets framework would be if you want the output to be in spreadsheet format and if you want to use the Apps Script's (free) scheduler. There are a number of challenges you face. You would need to make some head way yourself and ask more specific questions at StackOverflow.

Comment: The webpage you linked unfortunately does not have a well-formed xml structure. Otherwise, I would start you off with converting the html string to json and show you a simple, but also non-adaptable way to extract the information you need. But unfortunately it is not. See if you can find a html parser yourself and/or identify the exact substring of the html code where the code is a well-formed xml document. We can proceed from there.